# Heroku CLI failing in babun

Tags: windows, heroku, cygwin, command-line-interface, heroku-toolbelt

I am facing the following problem trying to use Heroku alongside [babun](http://babun.github.io/) on Windows 10, which is based on cygwin. I've installed the Heroku toolbelt on my Windows machine, and the CLI seems to be working in cmd:

[image: Heroku working on cmd]

However on babun I get the following error:

[image: Heroku not working in babun]

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\ruby-1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku (LoadError)
```

I think this might have something to do with babun's folder structure but I am struggling to fully diagnose.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is you are trying to run heroku CLI as a unix program when it was installed as a windows program.  This is tripping up the path with ruby.

Try run the Heroku bat file rather than the Unix shell script. You could even create an alias

```
alias heroku=heroku.bat
```

There is more explanation at https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/359

It could also be due to an older [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) installation.  There have been several updates with Heroku Toolbelt that improve the windows experience, so its worth running the latest version (if you are not already doing so)